# How to stop a shape in a slide from being edited or deleted?

Tags: onclick, slide, editing, shapes

I am new to vba and trying to create something like an `onClickEvent` in PowerPoint.

> I want to stop the editing and deleting of a shape named “xyz” which
>   has the tags for the slide.

I was trying to create a Event that detects the selection of this shape and then if it is deleted or edited, something as below;

```
If shape=”xyz” is the selected object then
Detect if {“DEL”} or {“BACKSPACE”} is pressed. Then AlertUser
```

The AlertUser is something like a message and then undoing the action

```
Public Sub AlertUser()
    MsgBox "Tags cannot be edited. This tag will be reset now."
    Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "Undo"
End Sub
```

Thanking in advance for your help and suggestions